# How to get value from JSON Dictionary using Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, json.net

I'm new in json and I have a little problem here that I can't solve.

In other json I have `{"certificate":"123456789",}` and I get the value of that using.

model.cs

```
class Login //this code is working.
{
    [JsonProperty("certificate")]
    public string certificate { get; set; }
}
```

But my problem is when I come up with json dictionary I don't have any Idea how can i get the value from it.

this is my code from controller.cs to get the json from Saba/api/component/location

```
using(var client = new HttpClient()) //I'm sure this code is working.
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(string.Format("https://{0}/", HostUrl));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("SabaCertificate", certificate);
            //HTTP GET: /Saba/api/componet/location
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("Saba/api/component/location");
            if(response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {

                Location saba = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Location>();
                //I always get empty location when I try to run the app.
            }
        }
```

This is JSON with dictionary.

```
{
"results": [
    {
        "loc_name": "Aberdeen - Aberdeen Town Square_489",
        "id": "locat000000000001877",
        "href": "https://na1.sabacloud.com/Saba/api/component/location/locat000000000001877"
    }]

}
```

How can I get the value of json dictionary?

What I've tried is

Model.cs

```
[JsonProperty("results")] \\ AggregateException Error
class Location
{
    [JsonProperty("loc_name")]
    public string loc_name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("href")]
    public string href { get; set; }
}
```

But I can't retrieve the value.

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. You have an opening `[`, but no closing `]`.

Comment: @Chips_100 Done editing :D

Comment: "it's not working" (which is what I assume you meant) gives us no information on *how* it's not working. Additionally, you haven't shown us what code isn't working - you've posted your class, but nothing about how you're trying to convert the JSON. Please post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem, including a clear behaviour of the expected behaviour and the actual behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the JSON posted in your question you should have something like

```
public class Result
{
    public string loc_name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string href { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
}
```

then just call

```
var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonData);
```

You can always use [JSON Formatter & Validator](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) to test if your JSON is valid, and [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) to generate c# classes from json.